# Hide navbar item for logged in users with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, authentication, uinavigationbar

I need help for login status change on my website. So basically I want an item on the navigation bar (let's say class name is "nav-item-3") to be visible to logged in users, but invisible to non-logged in users. And another item (class name is "nav-item-4") to be visible to non-logged in users, but invisible to logged in users.

I need a JavaScript code to accomplish that. Thank you.

Comment: If you need "a JavaScript code," have you tried writing one? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong? How are you determining whether a user is logged in, or not? Also: don't do this client-side, it should be handled on the server.

Comment: As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable; there are many ways to accomplish what you're asking and it's not possible for us to know which is appropriate for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You did not state what you are using as the storage for the login but if you are using local storage you can perform a check like:

```
!localStorage.getItem('userID')
```

and if the user is not logged in you can display a Nav.Item by writing:

```
!localStorage.getItem('userID') && (<Nav.Item></Nav.Item>)
```

This may not be the way you are storing the logins but you did not provide any additional information. Feel free to follow up.